# Обособление оборота «как обычно»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Встречаемся завтра, как обычно утром, не опаздывай!*

Обособляется или нет конструкция «как обычно»?
Каким правилом руководствоваться?

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае КАК ОБЫЧНО стоит в начале обособленной уточняющей конструкции КАК ОБЫЧНО УТРОМ, поэтому после КАК ОБЫЧНО запятая не нужна.

Если вводное слово (сочетание) стоит в начале или в конце обособленного оборота (обособления, уточнения, пояснения, присоединения), то никаким знаком препинания от оборота оно не отделяется. [Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=32)

***Встречаемся завтра, как обычно утром, не опаздывай!***

Comment: А восклицательный знак здесь оправдан? Не лучше ли поставить точку вместо второй запятой или в конце предложения?

Comment: На усмотрение автора. Всё зависит от интонации. Если вторая часть предложения произносится с восклицательной интонацией, то восклицательный знак нужен. Если нет - точка. Я тоже поставила бы точку после первой части:  "Встречаемся завтра, как обычно утром. Не опаздывай!" Но вопрос был об обособлении КАК ОБЫЧНО.

Answer (score 0):

Предложение желательно отредактировать, структура у него неестественная (с уточняющим, а не однородным  обстоятельством), вопрос о запятой будет  постоянно присутствовать.

**Встречаемся завтра утром, как обычно, не опаздывай!**

Пояснение

*Встречаемся завтра утром,  не опаздывай!* Неоднородные обстоятельства времени.

Добавлено вводное слово: *Встречаемся завтра утром, как обычно, не опаздывай!*

Вводное слово **по смыслу относится ко второму обстоятельству**: назначена встреча ―  на завтра,  а утреннее время  ― как обычно.